# Force square image crop during upload?

Tags: images, cropping

I'm developing my own theme where I have fixed the left sidebar with my photo. Is it possible to force users to crop their image to a square during upload? If yes, how? What functions I will need?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that all images are uploaded from a browser is false. Currently images can be uploaded via the XML-RPC protocol and once the REST API will be merged it will also be used to upload images.

Images can also be imported from other sites.

The point is that you should not assume that images are fitting the design. If you need images to look the best they can then you want not the cropped version but the full one and then let a pro designer to work on then to crop and fix them.

Comment: Ok, I see. So I ask, is possible force crop image after select? (Example: Theme Options->logo->upload/i select already uploaded image->crop->upload->save) I hope you understand me.

Comment: Yes you can crop the image after it has been uploaded to the server. Actually wordpress will do it automatically for several sizes, and you can add your own size by using the add_image_size API https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/, or write your own upload handler (there are many examples even on this site , just google for them).

Comment: And can I use `add_image_size` for something else like post thumbnail? Example for `get_theme_mod( 'image' )`?

Comment: add_image_size will cause all images uploaded via the wordpress API to automatically be cropped into the requested size. If you have a code that selects an image from the media library (so you get the image id), you can use get_attachment_image https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image to get the actual image tag (other related APIs can give just the url). The key parameter there is the $size which should match the $size you used in add_image_size.